# How to secure Elmah Page in RemoteAccess

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah.mvc

i have an ASP MVC web site that is published.

and i adjusted `<security allowRemoteAccess="yes"/>` in webconfig

and now anybody can access Elmah page

by saying that **i didnt use ASP.Net Identity**,how can i secure ELmah Page?

Comment: That was my querstion too .. Please help some one!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post a couple of months ago, that explains everything you need to know: [ELMAH security and allowRemoteAccess explained](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-security-and-allowremoteaccess-explained/). Basically, you will need to install the `Elmah.MVC` package and add app settings like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Admin" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="Thomas" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: i didnt use ASP.NET Identity

Comment: Not sure I understand?

Comment: you allowed Admin role and Thomas User that are in Identity Tables of asp,but i didnt use Identity

Comment: Ahh I see. I read is as you are using Identity. Sorry. How do you secure your pages then?

Comment: is it possible to override Elmah Controller?

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-security-and-allowremoteaccess-explained/#access-through-aspnet-authorization. As long as you set the username of the currently logged in user as the identity on the thread, I think that you will be able to secure the access to elmah.axd using that approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130599/discussion-between-ali7091-and-thomasardal).